# Updating numerical types using NoRM and other tools changes numerical type metadata on MongoDb

Tags: c#, orm, mongodb

We are using the NoRM C# driver to store our domain classes on mongodb. The problem we are facing is regarding external updates on this database. When trying to update an existing domain entity created originally using NoRM using an external tool such as mongo shell or MongoVUE numeric values are stored as different numeric types. Ie:  domain entities containing Int32 field values are updated as integer64 (MongoVUE) or float64 (mongo Shell).

**Original C# Entity:**

```
Class Person
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set;}
}
```

**Original Entity created using NoRM:**

```
{ Name: 'John Smith', Age: 16 }  // On MongoVUE Age field is shown as Int32
```

**Updated entity using MongoVUE:**

```
db.Test.update({Age:16}, {$set:{Age:22}})

{ Name: 'John Smith', Age: 22 }  // On MongoVUE Age field is shown as Int16
```

**Update Entity using Mongo Shell:**

```
db.Test.update({Age:22}, {$set:{Age:32}})

{ Name: 'John Smith', Age: 32 }  // On MongoVUE Age field is shown as Float64
```

When we try to retrieve an updated entity using NoRM depending on the tool used to perform the update NoRM fails to retrieve the entity.

So we need to specify somehow the numeric type metadata on the update query, but we’ve found no way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We experimented the same issue. Because of this and many other annoying things consider using 10gen driver (among theese NoRM driver beeing phased out)

http://groups.google.com/group/norm-mongodb/browse_thread/thread/2e44f73b2beaa984