# MongoDB C# : use official driver and Norm or wait for linq implementation, sugestions?

Tags: mongodb, norm, nosql

I searching to migrate my cms from SQL to NoSQL MongoDB using C#. I have created the first classes migration but i'm not happy with future evolutivity and stability using currents C# drivers. I have stated with Samus, moved to Norm and now mixed with Official mongodb driver. Can someone sugest what preserve in Norm driver and what use with official driver and when we can imagine to get a complete driver to stabilize the developments.
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using 10gen (official) driver for MongoDB, since it has been heavily refactored, tested and is currently maintained.

Norm driver is being phased out in favour of official driver 
 [Updating numerical types using NoRM and other tools changes numerical type metadata on MongoDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758404/updating-numerical-types-using-norm-and-other-tools-changes-numerical-type-metada/4782038#4782038)

On the top of 10gen driver you can add if really need [FluentMongo](https://github.com/craiggwilson/fluent-mongo).

Comment: Will FluentMongo integrate official driver ?. Exit some working project using this Linq implementation. Limitations?